Decomposing Hartree-Fock into orthogonalization step and unitary transformation step in PySCF
I have a basic question about mathematical details of Hartree-Fock. It seems there are two steps to obtaining canonical molecular orbitals (MOs) $\{\psi_i\}$ from atomic orbitals (AOs) $\{\phi_i\}$: (1) orthogonalize the AOs, and (2): apply a unitary transformation $U$ to the orthogonalized AOs to obtain MOs. To orthogonalize the AOs, one can apply the transformation $S^{-1/2}$ where
$$
S_{ij} = \langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle.
$$
If $C$ denotes the MO coefficient matrix, which defines transformation from AOs to MOs, then the above explanation suggests that
$$
C = U S^{-1/2},
$$
which would apply $S^{-1/2}$ to the target vector first, followed by $U$. However, based on some exploration in PySCF, it seems that the actual transformation is
$$
C' = S^{-1/2} U.
$$
See below for the code. My question is: which version is correct? I tried to find such an equation in an electronic structure textbook but was unable to.
import numpy as np
import pyscf as ps
import scipy.linalg

# define molecule and perform Hartree-Fock
geo = [
    ['H', [0,0,0]],
    ['H', [0,0,1]]
]
mol = ps.gto.Mole(
    atom=geo,
    basis='6-31g'
)
mol.build()

hf = ps.scf.RHF(molA)
hf.kernel()

# obtain C and overlap matrices
C             = hf.mo_coeff
S             = mol.intor('int1e_ovlp')
S_1over2      = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(S)
S_minus1over2 = np.linalg.inv(S_1over2)

# from these matrices, one can derive the unitary transformation U
# here, I tried every product of C with S_1over2, and S_minus1over2 that was possible,
# and the only one that returned a unitary is the following

U = S_1over2 @ C
assert np.allclose(U @ U.conj().T, np.identity(mol.nao)) # this assert is successful when I run this

assert np.allclose(C, S_minus1over2 @ U) # of course, by definition of U, this assert is successful


I can't look into this right now, but I would caution against using a molecule with such high symmetry for this. You may find artifacts of that symmetry instead of the verification you're looking for. OTOH, you can use a smaller basis set in this case.

This is not correct.
In restricted Hartree-Fock, you are solving the following equation until self-consistency:
$$FC = SCe$$
(As F depends on its solutions C this is a non-linear optimisation problem that is solved iteratively). The above eq is a generalised eigenvalue problem - note the overlap matrix $S$ that we don't really want there (i.e. would like it to be an identity matrix).
If we define $C = S^{-\frac{1}{2}} C'$ and plug it into the first equation, you get:
$$FC = SCe$$
$$FS^{-\frac{1}{2}} C'  = S S^{-\frac{1}{2}} C' e$$
Then if we multiply both sides on the left by $S^{-\frac{1}{2}}$:
$$S^{-\frac{1}{2}} FS^{-\frac{1}{2}} C'  = S^{-\frac{1}{2}} S S^{-\frac{1}{2}} C' e$$
We find:
$$S^{-\frac{1}{2}} FS^{-\frac{1}{2}}  = F'$$
$$S^{-\frac{1}{2}} S S^{-\frac{1}{2}} = I$$
Overall, the general eigenvalue problem is now a standard eigenvalue problem:
$$F' C'  = C' e$$
We can solve for the transformed orbital coefficient matrix $C'$
by diagonalizing the transformed Fock matrix $F'$ (using something like numpy.linalg.eigh).
To obtain $C$ we then just use our original def: $C = S^{-\frac{1}{2}} C'$. The RHF alg then goes back to the top of this answer and a new $F$ is obtained from this $C$... Defining a new $FC = SC e$. The same process is then used to obtain a new $C$... this is repeated until convergence. Advanced solvers will check the optimisation landscape to ensure the final  solution is a minima, but this can be expensive and is often omitted.
Important notes:

Any valid orthonormal MO basis satisfies: $C^{\dagger} S C = I$
The canonical MO basis has a specific definition.  They are a particular $C$ matrix, which diagonalize the Fock matrix and are obtained from a solution of a self-consistent field (SCF) calculation. (note they will also obey the first point). In your question hf.mo_coeff gives the canonical MOs (assuming the calculation has converged).

Extra:
If we start with an orthonormal MO basis $C_{init}$ (orthonormal meaning:  $C_{init}^{\dagger} S C_{init} = I$)
We can define a new valid basis MO basis as $C_{new} = C_{init} U$, where $U$ is a unitary. We observe:
$$ C_{new}^{\dagger} S C_{new} =  U^{\dagger }C_{init}^{\dagger} S C_{init} U = U^{\dagger } I U = I $$
and thus it should be easy to see there are infinitely many valid orthonormal MO bases - as $U$ is an arbitrary unitary matrix.
